# How to do homogenization of String in a DataFrame using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, automation

I need to do an homogenization for a huge number of string in cvs file, so i can use later for my work.
What i want to do is detect for example all string with the name LT_1,LT_2, LT_LCP, LT_.... and then convert these name to a single string LT.

I have a DataFrame in this form:

```
data = {'col_1': ["LT_1", "LT_2", "LT_NP", "LT_LCP", "GU","GU_I" , "GU_1","RH_1","RH_2","RY_1"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

[image]

I want to do an automation in order to do to that homogenization to all string in my Column col_1, in my real case, i have amore than 1000 strings in this format.

The expected output is like:

[image]

But note that the name of the Strings could be diffent than LT or GU or RH, it could be any String.

Thank you all

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I edited my post, you can now see an example of the output

Comment: Do they all follow the same format (your 1000 strings)

Comment: Yeah most of them, they start with a string and then an under score and then a number like. LT_1 or LT_2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `_` as separator, and grab the first item:

```py
>>> df1['col_1'] = df1['col_1'].str.split('_').str[0]
>>> df1
  col_1
0    LT
1    LT
2    LT
3    LT
4    GU
5    GU
6    GU
7    RH
8    RH
9    RY
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to write a function which performs the task you want, then `apply()` it to the dataframe.

```
def homogenize(row):
    if '_' in row['col_1']:
        return row['col_1'].split('_')[0]

    return row['col_1']

df1['col_1'] = df1.apply(lambda x: homogenize(x), axis=1)
```

---

Output

```
  col_1
0    LT
1    LT
2    LT
3    LT
4    GU
5    GU
6    GU
7    RH
8    RH
9    RY
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting my two cents in, you could use

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'(^[^_]+)')
df1['col_1'] = df1['col_1'].apply(lambda x: rx.search(x).group(1))
print(df1)
```

Which yields

```
  col_1
0    LT
1    LT
2    LT
3    LT
4    GU
5    GU
6    GU
7    RH
8    RH
9    RY
```

Note: will throw an error for empty fields. You could build a function around it that checks if `.group(1)` is actually set.